# Is it possible to integrate Moralis server with Rinkeby testnet?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, moralis

I'd like to integrate my Moralis server to Rinkeby testnet but did not find any documentation about it. Is it possible? How are the steps to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moralis supports Rinkeby. It has API, syncing events, and speedy nodes for this chain.

https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-server/web3-sdk/intro#supported-chains